# REST API GET request - python gives HTTP 404, curl gives HTTP 200

Tags: python-3.x, rest, python-requests

I'm accessing a REST API to fetch some data using python (request module/python3.6) and for some resources it gives HTTP 404 error, and if i use the same URL using curl it gives the response with 200.

I have checked the following.
 1) Response body size is not larger for those responses
 2) there are no redirects, or permanent redirects. (no cross origin resource sharing)

what can cause this issue. Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Can you post the URL so others can try?

Comment: Its actually an internal URL. I'm confusing about the status code difference, it's 200 from curl but 404 from python side, even i tried url-lib3 as well. no luck yet .

Comment: First bet would be to try running curl with ‘-I’ to show the headers and compare with the Python request ‘response.headers’ . You may also want to try experimenting with adding or removing a trailing slash as this can sometimes have an effect.

Comment: yes, i tried that as well.

Comment: Then it sounds like the 404 is not a true “not found” but rather a “not telling”. Have you tried manually setting the Python request header User-Agent to the value set by Curl? It may have a Disallow directive set somewhere.